# ejecutar archivo .bat desde cliente

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, batch

Quiero ejecutar un archivo bat alojado en una carpeta de un servidor la cual es una carpeta compartida.
En la misma locacion creo otros tipos de archivos y el acceso no es el problema.

Estoy ejecutando con este codigo, pasa por el if pero no ejecuta el archivo .bat y tampoco manda algun error.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process launcher = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            launcher.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\servername\carpetacompartida\file.bat";
            if (launcher.Start())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("EL archivo .bat fue ejecutado");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se ejecuto");
            }
```

Como se que no se esta ejecutando? por que al ternimar de ejecutarse el archivo .bat genera automaticamente un file.txt como log, este se crea cuado se ejecuta el .bat si no aparece es porque no se ejecuto el .bat.

Comment: Creo que por tema de seguridad no se podria ejecutar un bat en servidor, seria facil de ejecutar virus.

Comment: es para uso en una red privada, dificilmente creo que suceda lo que comentas.